# Seaching windows environment for a specific value

Tags: powershell

I want to search the windows environment variables for a specific string

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Env: | TEE-OBJECT -variable newvar1 | grep windir $newvar1
```

It works for first time

```
STDIN
windir                         C:\WINDOWS
```

and then fails the subsequent times

```
grep: Could not open 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry'
```

How do i remove old variables from the dictionary (if that is the problem)?

Answer (score 1):

### Part 1 - Root Cause

Your core problem is `grep windir $newvar1` - the command line parameters for `grep` are (from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ```
> grep searches for PATTERNS in each FILE.
> ```

You're asking grep to search in a **file** (`$newvar1`), not the input stream. Each entry in `$newvar1`, gets serialised as the literal string `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` so grep is basically looking for a file called `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`, which doesn't exist.

### Part 2 - Solution

The best bet is to go full idiomatic PowerShell and use [@JPBlanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73146916/3156906), but if you're really wedded to grep just remove the trailing `$newvar` to use the input stream (stdin) instead of a file for input:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Env: `
    | TEE-OBJECT -variable newvar1 `
    | grep windir
```

or, if you don't actually need the values stored in `$newvar1` for downstream processing, just simply:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Env: `
    | grep windir
```

### Part 3 - Why no error the first time?

Your original command *works* the first time because `$newvar1` isn't defined yet, so it's equivalent to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Env: `
    | TEE-OBJECT -variable newvar1 `
    | grep windir $null
```

... so grep is defaulting to searching the input stream (stdin) rather than a file.

You can confirm this if you enable strict mode - you'll get this error from PowerShell instead:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest";

Get-ChildItem -Path Env: `
    | TEE-OBJECT -variable newvar1 `
    | grep windir $newvar1

# InvalidOperation:
# Line |
#    3 |      | grep term $newvar1
#      |                  ~~~~~~~~
#      | The variable '$newvar1' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
```

The **second** time you run the commnad, `$newvar1` is already initialised with the results from the first time, so it's equivalent to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Env: `
    | TEE-OBJECT -variable newvar1 `
    | grep windir "System.Collections.DictionaryEntry"
```

which, as we've seen, tells grep to look for a file called `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`, and results in an error.

### Part 4 - More details

Note that `$newvar1` isn't defined in the first call to grep because `Tee-Object` only creates the variable in its [End block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#end) once it's processed all of its pipeline input (see the source code for [Tee-Object.cs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7dc4587014bfa22919c933607bf564f0ba53db2e/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/Tee-Object.cs#L140) on GitHub), which doesn't happen until the entire pipeline has been processed, including the downstream calls to grep.

Not that it's very useful, but you can *force* the first command to fail by doing this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path Env: | TEE-OBJECT -variable newvar1) `
    | grep windir $newvar1

# /usr/bin/grep: System.Collections.DictionaryEntry: No such file or directory
```

Wrapping the first two expressions in a [Grouping Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--) forces the pipeline inside to be fully evaluated first, which means `Tee-Object`'s End block creates the `$newvar1` variable before grep is invoked, and we get the file-searching behaviour instead of the input stream behaviour.

Comment: Fantastically clear answer.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You an try :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Env: | Where-object {$_.value -like 'C:\Users*'}
```

`Get-ChildItem` returns a list of objects with properties `Name` and `value`. Then Where-object, allow you to filter on these properties, `$_` representthe object, you can choose the operator (in this case `-like`) in the list of Powershell operators).

Comment: That works well.  still curious to know why my original command only works once